# Does PHP's pg_fetch_assoc() use an Iterator/Cursor?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, iterator, php-pgsql

Does the PHP function [`pg_fetch_assoc()`](https://php.net/pg_fetch_assoc) internally

use an Iterator / Cursor, or does it get all data at once, network-wise?

Would `\PDO` be using a Cursor?

*My context is fetching a large amount of data and I want to know if it gets pulled as a whole or row by row (or limited rows by rows when the cursor holds a subset of the full dataset).*

Comment: My experience is that it fetches all at once because I've received memory allocation errors using it if I received too many rows. However, MySQL and ORA versions of fetch_assoc have never given me memory allocation errors. Disclaimer: I haven't used PG functions since 2009, so the function implementation may be different now.

Comment: re: your edit - memory allocated on return, or on passing?

Comment: @treyBake does the whole dataset get pulled from the db server or only the data in the cursor (I've not downvoted your answer); (changed wording from "memory allocation" to "data getting pulled as a whole or partially");

Comment: @DanielW. data in the cursor I believe, as we're passing in the $result as a param instead of creating it all in the function :)

Answer (score 2):

`pg_fetch_assoc()` does neither. It is a function which fetches an associative array from a PHP resource. The resource can be for example the result of the call to [`PQexecPrepared`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-exec.html).

On API level PHP-pgsql does not have cursor functions. You could try using PDO, which emulates cursors for PostgreSQL if you enable the scrollable cursor mode. See [`prepare()` for more details.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) Another alternative is to just use the SQL cursor statements yourself.

This answer explains a little bit more: [php postgres from query to fetching rows in theory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350067/1839439)

Here is a link to [PDO source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_statement.c#L131), which is responsible for emulating cursors with SQL statements.

Answer (score -1):

The data is passed via $result:

(Taken from the `pgsql.php` file that opens (`CTRL + Click` on function name in PHPStorm)):

```
/**
 * Fetch a row as an associative array
 * @link https://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php
 * @param resource $result <p>
 * PostgreSQL query result resource, returned by <b>pg_query</b>,
 * <b>pg_query_params</b> or <b>pg_execute</b>
 * (among others).
 * </p>
 * @param int $row [optional] <p>
 * Row number in result to fetch. Rows are numbered from 0 upwards. If
 * omitted or <b>NULL</b>, the next row is fetched.
 * </p>
 * @return array An array indexed associatively (by field name).
 * Each value in the array is represented as a
 * string. Database NULL
 * values are returned as <b>NULL</b>.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * <b>FALSE</b> is returned if <i>row</i> exceeds the number
 * of rows in the set, there are no more rows, or on any other error.
 * @since 4.3
 * @since 5.0
 */
function pg_fetch_assoc ($result, $row = null) {}
```

The rows in `$result` is a numbered array/object, containing all data it has.  It simply returns the row in that array/object, so it deals with whatever data is in the passed cursor. We can get this from one of the lines from the above code (formatted for better reading):

> @param resource $result
>   PostgreSQL query result resource, returned by 
>   pg_query, pg_query_params or pg_execute

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I think you missed a point a little bit. Reading between the lines I think OP wants to know how to use cursor mode with PG api.

Comment: @Dharman ahh, I'm a bit too literal sometimes haha :) I'll wait for OP to comment/respond and I'll amend accordingly (if I can) :)